# Mostrar u ocultar columnas de Grid Angular

Tags: angular, grid

Requiero mostrar u ocultar una columna de un grid estando en ejecución el sistema, para lograrlo he intentado cambiar una variable a estado de true o false y enviarla al [visible], asi...

```
              <e-column field='nivel' editType='dropdownedit' [edit]="nivelVariable" textAlign='Center'
                headerText='Nivel' width=100 [visible]='pGridColumnaNivelVisible'>
              </e-column>
```

tambien he intentado meter la columna dentro de un div o un contenedor y mandarle al [hidden] true o false, asi

```
            <div [hidden]='pGridColumnaNivelVisible == false'>
              <e-column field='nivel' editType='dropdownedit' [edit]="nivelVariable" textAlign='Center'
                headerText='Nivel' width=100 >
              </e-column>
            </div>
```

pero no he logrado ocultar y mostrar la columna desde tiempo de ejecucion.

**¿Es posible?**

Answer (score 0):

```
this.gridVirtuales.showColumns(['Nivel', 'Cualquier otra columna']); // show by HeaderText
this.gridVirtuales.hideColumns(['Nivel', 'Cualquier otra columna']); // hide by HeaderText
```